Microsoft Active Directory - Get Users Displayname with [System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal]::Current Error Attribute
For some time now I´m trying to find the error in my AD.
I need to run a software that is using the .NET 6 [System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal]::Current to get the Current Users Displayname. This is working if I am logged in as a Domain Admin but not working for default users.
In a freshly set up domain it also works fine for all users.
Does anyone of you has some ideas to fix that? Re-doing the whole domain is not possible right now.
If I try to do the following in PowerShell:
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$user = Get-ADUser -Identity "deinBenutzername" -Properties DisplayName
$user.DisplayName

it works despite being a normal user.
If I try as a default user:
Add-Type -AssemblyName "System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement"
$context = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext([System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ContextType]::Domain)
$userPrincipal = [System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal]::Current
$displayName = $userPrincipal.DisplayName

The Output I get is:

Das angegebene Verzeichnisdienstattribut bzw. der angegebene
Verzeichnisdienstwert ist nicht vorhanden. In Zeile:2 Zeichen:1

$userPrincipal = [System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrin ...

  + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], COMException
  + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException




Which means: The specified directory service attribute or value does not exist
If I try this as a domain admin it works!
I also tried:

Adding Full access permission to SELF on the test user (logging out, restarting, all of this)
Adding Full access permission to the Account itself (Domain\Testuser...)
Adding Read permission to read all AD users / attributes


If Get-ADUser is available on the computers you will run this on, then you can use the environment variables to get the user's domain and username:
$user = Get-ADUser -Server $env:USERDNSDOMAIN -Identity $env:USERNAME

Without using Get-ADUser, you can use ADSI and WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent() to get the user's SID and get the account that way:
$u = [ADSI]"LDAP://$($env:USERDNSDOMAIN)/<SID=$([System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent().User.Value)>"
$u.Properties["displayName"]

However, I've found that the ADSI method doesn't work if you have a hybrid Azure / on-prem AD environment.
